# How to check if marquee is scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

How to detect if marquee is scrolling on button click using jQuery?

```html
<marquee>Scrolling text here, moving constantly</marquee>

<button id="btnCheck">Button</button>
```

My jQuery code looks like:

```
$(function (){

   var marquee = $("marquee")[0];

  $("#btnCheck").click(function (){
     // How to check if marquee is scrolling here
  });
});
```

Comment: It needs to be said. The `<marquee>` tag does not exist in any HTML specification. While it does have a write up in the current HTML5 spec, it's there only for the purpose of marking it as obsolete. I've forgotten the details. Do not use `<marquee>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `p` inside the `marquee` and check its `left` position. If it is changed, then your `marquee` is scrolling, otherwise, it is not, like this snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btnCheck").click(function() {
        var initialLeft = $('marquee > p').position().left;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var currentLeft = $('marquee > p').position().left;

            if (initialLeft !== currentLeft) {
                alert("Marquee is scrolling!");
            }else{
                alert("Marquee is not scrolling");
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee loop="1"><p>Scrolling text here, moving constantly</p></marquee>
<button id="btnCheck">Button</button>
```

---

P/s:

> This (The HTML `<marquee>`) feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.

Refer: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: I have others button that starts and stop the marquee. I tried to integrate it, but many times initialLeft and currentLeft equals, therefore always alerting as scrolling even though the scroll had stopped. Did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe the speed of your marquee is slower than default, then the timeout time of `setTimeout` is not enough, try increasing it to a bigger value in the part of `}, 100);`